# asp net 2.0 EnableEventValidation = False

Tags: asp.net

This isn't so much a question as to more of a quick tip on some issues I had with my GridView export to Excel..

So I was having the problem that when I exported a GridView to excel spreadsheet, the spreadsheet was essentially blank however strangely enough a couple fields were filled with a tad bit of html (`<div>, </div>`).. I couldn't really figure out why that was happening but I stumbled upon a link which fixed my issue:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/45450/RegisterForEventValidation-can-only-be-called-duri

So for my solution I just added the `EnableEventValidation=False` in the top of my form and I neglected to add the bit of `Me.EnableViewState = False` in the behind code. This worked for whatever reason..

Question: Could someone explain what the heck is going on? I feel like every time I get something working with Asp.net it feels like I am mostly just exploiting bugs in the framework to get code working as opposed to using a logical flow like other frameworks I've used.. I still don't understand how something like this can just 'magically' work now and I have know understanding of the reasons why.

It's like if I were to program: A is in B and B is in C.. Therefore A is in C.

Case 1:
RoR: Ok, A is in C, your right mr. programmer, I get it.
Me: Yay, ok on the the next task..

Case 2:
Asp.net: Must set inheritor for object C.. see stacktrace...etc
Me: oh.. hmm ok I'll google that error:.. 45 min later.. Oh here is something weird that doesn't contain any useful docs... I'll try that. Oh it works! Yaay, but lame. I dun get it.

Comment: have you checked documentaion before ??  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx